# Using pdfkit, how can I write to separate files?

Tags: python-2.7, pdfkit

I have multiple htm files in a directory. I used pdfkit to convert to pdf files. Converting works perfectly fine, but I do not know how to write converted pdf's into separate files. Right now, it just overwrites the previous file. Please help. I really appreciated it.

**I tried options using "no-collate" but the error **ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required pops up**

I think the best way is to (1) convert to pdf and (2) save the file in a sequence. But I just can't figure out with pdfkit module. Please help. Thank you!

```
import pdfkit
import os
import requests

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\phill\\Desktop\\10k\\HTML')


def htmltopdf(filename):
    pdfkit.from_file([file], '8k.pdf', 'no-collate')



files=os.listdir('C:\\Users\\phill\\Desktop\\10k\\HTML')
for file in files:
    if ".htm" in file:
        htmltopdf(file)
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you add what you have already tried, so that people don't give you advice on what you have already eliminated?

Comment: @user230910 I added what I tried. Thank you!